# Docker command at startup time getting error

Tags: docker

Try to add start up command to a container got error

> "docker container commit" requires at least 1 and at most 2 arguments.

docker container commit  --change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/HaselCastCache.jar"]' blissful_germain syedwn14/haselcastcache:manual2

"docker container commit" requires at least 1 and at most 2 arguments.
See 'docker container commit --help'.

Usage:  docker container commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

Create a new image from a container's changes

Comment: Please attach your image's Dockerfile to the question, so we know how to reproduce the issue.  (You should probably never use `docker commit` at all.)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the line seems to be unusable in Windows as Windows requires literals in the command line to be in double-quotes. There's no option for using a single quote like in MAC and Unix.

> docker container commit --change="CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/HaselCastCache.jar"]" blissful_germain   syedwn14/haselcastcache:manual2

Answer (score 1):

Is `docker container commit` valid command?

Try with `docker commit`:

```
 docker commit --change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/HaselCastCache.jar"]' blissful_germain   syedwn14/haselcastcache:manual2
```

Valid syntax:

```
docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: I tried `docker container commit` on Docker 19.03 and it was working fine.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_commit/

Comment: Ok, so if you have 19.03.01 it should work in the same way for docker container commit. I've tested that locally without any issues. Are you pasting your command from clipboard or typing manually?

Comment: $ docker container commit --change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/HaselCastCache.jar"]' blissful_germain openjdk
sha256:b7477d2e62cabed86820a8dabc0975e1e64610ff0b902723eef91332d1faeed3
[node1] (local) root@192.168.0.23 ~
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.4

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, switch to **PowerShell** instead of CMD. your command will run without any error.

docker commit --change='CMD ["java","-jar","/tmp/HaselCastCache.jar"]' blissful_germain syedwn14/haselcastcache:manual2